# Vue JS: this.$on event doesn't contain passed parameters

Tags: events, parameters, vue.js

Here are my components. I've successfully emitted parameters from the child component to the parent, but not from the parent to the child. The `console.log('In initDetail()');` line fires, which means the `$on` event is triggered, but `param` is undefined. I'm wondering why.

Parent component:

```
components: {
  "child-component": ChildComponent
}
methods: {
  loadDetail() {
    this.$emit('loadDetailEvent', 'test');
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
mounted() {
  this.$on('loadDetailEvent', this.initDetail(param)); 
}
methods: {
  initDetail(param) {
    console.log('In initDetail()');
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

I've also tried calling a function right away. Neither the `console.log('$on event');` nor the `console.log(param);` lines print.

```
this.$on('loadDetailEvent', function(param){
  console.log('$on event');
  console.log(param);
});
```

Comment: `this.$on` should receive a callback, e.g. a function as the second argument. But you execute a function right away. Try to change to `this.$on('loadDetailEvent', this.initDetail)`.

Comment: To add to what @wostex said, to perform multiple actions on the event you could make a fat arrow function: `  this.$on('loadDetailEvent', (data) => {this.initDetail(data); console.log(data);}); `

Comment: @wostex @Antony thanks for your answers. However, I tried both without success. If I change `this.$on('loadDetailEvent', this.initDetail)` to `this.$on('loadDetailEvent', this.initDetail())`, my `initDetail` function fires, but `param` is still undefined. I wonder if my scope is wrong somehow.

Comment: While everyone else is so focused on your `$on` setup, they've failed to address something more fundamentally wrong: I don't believe that child components can handle events emitted by their parent! In particular, you can only emit events from child to parent, not from parent to child. If you want parent to child communication, you should be mutating `props` passed down from the parent and `watch`ing for changes in your child component.

Comment: Expounding upon what @B.Fleming said, you can also use a `Bus` system where you invoke an entirely new `Vue` instance meant to act as an event bus.

Comment: Thanks @B. Fleming, I didn't realize you couldn't emit from parent to child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there are a couple misconceptions in your code:

1. Your parent component is emitting a `loadDetailEvent` event when the `loadDetail` method is called. Your child component is also listening for a `loadDetailEvent` event, but it will only handle this event if it is emitted by *its own Vue instance*. If the Vue instance of the parent emits an event, the child will have no knowledge of it.
2. You are attempting to handle the `loadDetailEvent` by firing `initDetail` and passing the parameters of the event to that method. But, in your code you are simply setting the `loadDetailEvent` handler to be the result of calling `this.initDetail(param)` within the scope of the `mounted` hook. What you would want to do in this case would be to specify an anonymous function as the handler, which receives the `param` value and passes it to `this.initDetail`:

   ```
    this.$on('loadDetailEvent', (param) => this.initDetail(param))
   ```

---

But, to get at the root of your issue: it seems like you want to call a child method when a parent method is called. You could do this a few different ways:

1. As @Ohgodwhy suggested, you could create a separate, global Vue instance to use as an event bus.
2. You could set a `ref` (say `ref="child"`) on the child component tag in your parent's template and then call the child component's method directly via `this.$refs.child.initDetail('test')`.
3. As @B.Fleming suggested, you could set a watcher on the child component to react to a changing prop value passed by the parent component. This gets a little tricky since you would need to maintain the value of the variable being passed as the prop (I would use a [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier), as you can see below).

### Here are example snippets of the above solutions:

#### Using an event bus:

```js
let EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>Child</div>`,
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('loadDetailEvent', (param) => this.initDetail(param)); 
  },
  methods: {
    initDetail(param) {
      console.log('In initDetail()');
      console.log(param);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    loadDetail() {
      EventBus.$emit('loadDetailEvent', 'test');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child></child>
  <button @click="loadDetail">load</button>
</div>
```

#### Using a `ref`:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>Child</div>`,
  methods: {
    initDetail(param) {
      console.log('In initDetail()');
      console.log(param);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    loadDetail() {
      this.$refs.child.initDetail('test');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child ref="child"></child>
  <button @click="loadDetail">load</button>
</div>
```

#### Using a `prop` value and a watcher:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>Child</div>`,
  props: { loading: String },
  methods: {
    initDetail(param) {
      console.log('In initDetail()');
      console.log(param);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    loading(val) {
      if (val) {
        this.initDetail(val);
        this.$emit('update:loading', '');
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { payload: '' }
  },
  methods: {
    loadDetail() {
      this.payload = 'test';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child :loading.sync="payload"></child>
  <button @click="loadDetail">load</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @thanksd. The bus system is working. I appreciate your quick reply.

Comment: You can also pass the parameter by this way:
`EventBus.$on('loadDetailEvent', this.initDetail);` — it will be passed to `initDetail` as is.